# How to use email template files and stylize emails in OroCRM

Tags: email, templates, commerce, orocrm, orocommerce

There are just two questions:

1. How can I use email template files instead of managing email content
   from the Back Office in OroCRM?
2. How can I stylize email templates in OroCRM?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create email templates from code with data fixtures. For more details see the developer documentation - [OroCommerce Email Templates](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/emails/).
2. You can stylize email templates within OroCommerce the same way as any other HTML templates. To support most of the email providers, styles must be inlined into HTML.